# File comparison - Code and others

Tags: filesystems, comparison, beyondcompare

We have a requirement to compare two sets of files, for content similarity

Folder A - 100 files
Folder B - 150 files

The comparison will be with each file in Folder A against each file in Folder B. BeyondCompare offers that functionality, but we have to manually open each of the 'Compare against' file in Folder B.

Is there a tool that runs through this whole MxN scenario and provide a report of similarity %?

Comment: What constitutes a similarity? Do you want each file scanned byte by byte or just checking file names?

Comment: Filenames are definitely different. So, we need the content compared.

Comment: Whether any file in Folder A, contains all/part of content from a file in Folder B.

Comment: So byte by byte for each file too?

Comment: If BeyondCompare gives you the percentage you need, all you need to do is call it in a nested `for` loop.

Comment: What is your OS : Windows, Linux, Max ? Which version?

Comment: Windows @Pacopaco

Comment: @AFH Unfortunately BeyondCompare doesn't give percentage I think. However I'd settle for highlights, I can scroll through.

Comment: @EricF if by byte by byte you mean compare contents, yes.

Comment: I'm not sure that scrolling through up to 15000 files will solve your problem. I can't begin to think how one would attach a meaningful percentage to a comparison. You my be able to use the Unix `file` program to limit the comparisons to between similar file types.

Comment: The best bet would be to write your own of course but if you don't program then that is not a solution

Comment: Beyond Compare doesn't support displaying percentage similarity. If you run a rules-based comparison, it will compare the text contents of files, which can ignore minor differences like comments and whitespace. In the Folder Compare, click the Rules toolbar button, check Compare Contents, then select Rules-based comparison.